What to do when blog post are better indexed than product pages?
I'm Mihaela, and I own https://sporulcasei.ro/.
Initially, https://sporulcasei.ro/ was a blog about home and garden topics, then I added the store to it.
Gradually, I removed a significant part of the blog content, with the necessary redirects, and created more content aimed at directing traffic to the product categories in the store.
However, the blog pages are still indexed much better, as seen in Google Search Console.
What could I do to improve the indexing of product pages?
I should mention that some blog posts still aren’t related to the store.
Would excluding these from indexing be beneficial?

Do you mean pages aren't indexed at all or they aren't position well within search results?

Schema code can help understand to Google what is your product. But also will depend how competitive is your local area. Build backlinks related to your industry pointing to your product pages. From what I read you are doing the right thing, writing topics to sale your products. I hope this helps!
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/product
